# Excel not closing files when closing window

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

On one specific PC I get this behavior where closing a window won't free the corresponding xls/xslx file.
I can see the temporary file and cannot delete the original. Only when all windows are closed excel frees all file resources at once.
This is true for network shares as well as local folders.

I'm looking for an explanation so I'll be able to circumvent or fix the problem.

I'd rule out the antivirus (Kaspersky) because it is the same on all PCs and doesn't have suspicious settings.

Comment: Do you have cross references between different excel files?

Comment: Possibly, but certainly not as a rule. More often than not references will be in vbscript macros rather than formulas. My colleague added that the problem may affect Word too and possibly other programs but as he uses almost only excel he's not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the user had installed a misbehaving program without authorization, possibly without even knowing.
Right now the problem seems solved.